# Trying to include a .h library in NetBeans 6.9.1

Tags: c++, c, netbeans

I have a line like this below in the Main.cpp file in my C++ project.

```
include<GL/glut.h>
```

When I try to compile the project, it says:

> GL/glut.h: No such file or directory.

The path of the file I'm trying to include is root_project/include/GL/glut.h.

What should I do?

Regards,
Javi

Answer (score 0):

you should make sure that in the project settings of netbeans, 'include directories' includes the path of the directory which contains the folder "GL"